# closing weak questions

Tags: discussion, closing

I'm trying to do my part clearing the close vote queue. Here's one with an accepted answer:

[Vector addition of opposing vectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2787612/vector-addition-of-opposing-vectors)

It deserves to be closed since it shows no work. It's unlikely to be of use to anyone else. But closing it takes time (mine and that of others). Why do we bother? It has an accepted answer, so won't show up on the unanswered queue. I think trying to prune all the bad questions is a hopeless task.

I wonder too about similar questions (some with answers) that appear as "too old to migrate" when I vote to close. Could closing them be automated?

Comment: Note that you can find a lot of poor questions at one go from [this list](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/835119) There are false positives, but rarely.

Comment: Weak questions? SAD.

Comment: What exactly would you want to automate? That is, what should be the criterion? Note that deletion is automated to some extent (even for non closed questions).

Comment: @quid Not sure what I'd automate. Just wondering if there's a good way to save some user time here.

Comment: @quid  Are you referring to the auto deletion of questions which have been closed, have a non-positive score, and have no answers with a positive vote count?  How/when does this occur for non-closed questions (heavily downvoted, perhaps?).

Comment: I do think it is a valid concern to point out that quality control on site *does take time and effort*, which is not rewarded in any way, (aside from early on when one earns a badge or two).  For users with limited time who want to garner rep, the current set up encourages them to *do nothing but answer questions, of any sort*, and not spend time investing in helping to maintain the site they seek to benefit from.  So it is a valid concern.  Why should some users have to use there time to clean up after other users, and not get any reward whatsoever for doing so?

Comment: Yet if no one volunteered, quietly, with no form of reward, to help clean up the site, just as if no one volunteered, to moderate this site, with no form of reward, this site wouldn't exist.  What's wrong with this picture?

Comment: Don't get me wrong... I'm not arguing that janitorial tasks to make this site workable should earn rep.  But the tasks and the work of those who do them behind the scenes never get noticed, until someone objects to one of $0.001\%$ of such janitorial work, at which point, all hell breaks loose, and witch-hunts begin for the devoted users *actually willing* to do the janitorial work others would rather avoid.

Comment: @amWhy open ones are deleted if it seems no one cares about the question. Score zero, unanswered, few or no comments, few views, means deletion after a year. (It is debatable if this is even good; reasonable but highly specialized questions can be deleted in this way.)

Comment: Thanks, @quid.  I didn't know that.

Comment: @amWhy I'm quite willing to continue spending some time helping clean up. I don't need to be rewarded for it. I'm just asking if there's a way to make the time I do spend go farther. Maybe such steps have already been taken.

Comment: I wasn't addressing you, @Ethan, or suggesting that you're looking for anything to get out of it.  I just think that if most users would realize the investment of time, and appreciate it, we'd feel better about the time we do spend cleaning up.  I completely support finding ways to make such time more effective, more efficient.

Comment: I think we should rather be concerned about weak* questions.

Comment: @User What do you mean by weak-$*$?  It seems rather vague to me...

Comment: @amWhy the rules on automated deletion is documented on [help/roomba](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/roomba)